# How to convert string to valid json or yaml

Tags: python, json

I have a large script that parses js with a dataframe entry, but to shorten the question, I put what I need in a separate variable.
My variable contains the following value

```
value = "{from:[3,4],to:[7,4],color:2},{from:[3,6],to:[10,6],color:3}"
```

I apply the following script and get data like this

```
value = "{from:[3,4],to:[7,4],color:2},{from:[3,6],to:[10,6],color:3}"

def parse_json(value):
    arr = value.split("},")
    arr = [x+"}" for x in arr]
    arr[-1] = arr[-1][:-1]
    
    return json.dumps({str(i):add_quotation_marks(x) for i, x in enumerate(arr)})

def add_quotation_marks(value):
    words = re.findall(r'(\w+:)', value)
    for word in words:
        value = value.replace(word[:-1], f'"{word[:-1]}"')
    return json.loads(value)

print(parse_json(value))
```

```
{"0": {"from": [3, 4], "to": [7, 4], "color": 2}, "1": {"from": [3, 6], "to": [10, 6], "color": 3}}
```

The script executes correctly, but I need to get a slightly different result.
This is what the result I want to get looks like:

```
{
  "0": {
    "from": {
      "0": "3",
      "1": "4"
    },
    "to": {
      "0": "7",
      "1": "4"
    },
    "color": "2"
  },
  "1": {
    "from": {
      "0": "3",
      "1": "6"
    },
    "to": {
      "0": "10",
      "1": "6"
    },
    "color": "3"
  }
}
```

This is valid json and valid yaml. Please tell me how can I do this

Comment: You can use `enumerate` and `dict` on the list values. E.g., `dict(enumerate([3, 4]))` gives `{0: 3, 1: 4}`. Btw., if you do `value.strip('{}').split('},{')`, in the first line, you can omit `element.replace` lines.

Comment: Why do you have data in this format to begin with? Is this some documented format for which a parser exists? Are you getting this from somewhere, or have you created that string yourself? If the latter, can't you use something else?

Comment: I have a script, the essence of which is that it parses the js file, takes data from there and puts it in a dataframe with subsequent writing to the database. The variable I've provided is a value from one row of one column of the dataframe, as an example. The data in the dataframe is exactly as I presented it in the variable. And I need to convert these values ​​​​to the format that I presented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code that converts the the `value` to your desired output.

```py
import json5  # pip install json5

value = "{from:[3,4],to:[7,4],color:2},{from:[3,6],to:[10,6],color:3}"

def convert(str_value):
    str_value = f"[{str_value}]"  # added [] to make it a valid json
    parsed_value = json5.loads(str_value)  # convert to python object
    output = {}  # create empty dict

    # Loop through the list of dicts. For each item, create a new dict
    # with the index as the key and the value as the value. If the value
    # is a list, convert it to a dict with the index as the key and the
    # value as the value. If the value is not a list, just add it to the dict.
    for i, d in enumerate(parsed_value):
        output[i] = {}
        for k, v in d.items():
            output[i][k] = {j: v[j] for j in range(len(v))} if isinstance(v, list) else v

    return output

print(json5.dumps(convert(value)))
```

Output

```json
{
  "0": {     
    "from": {
      "1": 4
    },
    "to": {
      "0": 7,
      "1": 4
    },
    "color": 2
  },
  "1": {
    "from": {
      "0": 3,
      "1": 6
    },
    "to": {
      "0": 10,
      "1": 6
    },
    "color": 3
  }
}
```

- `json5` package allows you to convert a javascrip object to a python dictionary so you dont have to do `split("},{")`.
- Then added `[` and `]` to make the string a valid json.
- Then load the string using `json5.loads()`
- Now you can loop through the dictionary and convert it to desired output format.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a regex approach in this case:

```
res = []

# iterates over each "{from:...,to:...,color:...}" group separately
for obj in re.findall(r'\{([^}]+)}', value):
    item = {}

    # iterates over each "...:..." key-value separately
    for k, v in re.findall(r'(\w+):(\[[^]]+]|\d+)', obj):
        if v.startswith('['):
            v = v.strip('[]').split(',')

        item[k] = v

    res.append(item)
```

This produces this output in `res`:

```
[{'from': ['3', '4'], 'to': ['7', '4'], 'color': '2'}, {'from': ['3', '6'], 'to': ['10', '6'], 'color': '3'}]
```

Since your values can contain commas, trying to split on commas or other markers is fairly tricky, and using these regexes to match your desired values instead is more stable.